# In Visual studio, what is the command to select single word mentioned in different places in file

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Mac user here.
In Visual Studio Code there is a key combination: `command + d`
to select variable name everywhere in the file.
What is the equivalent command in Visual Studio 2022 on mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is called `Multi-Caret`.

Here is the documentation: [Multi-caret editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/multi-caret-editing?view=vsmac-2022).